# redirect parameters - how to combine GeoIP , iphone redirects and randomization

Tags: iphone, ipad, redirect, random, geoip

I'm totally newbie to php, just trying to solve some my own tasks.
The task is: to redirect users correctly to several affiliate links according their country, user agent and in some cases, I need to show user with specific country randomly a couple of links.

so, I began with the following code (Maxmind geoip used):

```
<?php

include("geoip.inc");

$gi=geoip_open("geoip.dat",GEOIP_STANDARD);
$cc=geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

if($cc=="US")  header("Location: http://domain1.com");
if($cc=="AU")  header("Location: http://domain2.com");
if($cc=="CA")  header("Location: http://domain3.com");

geoip_close($gi);


if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad"))
 {
 header("Location: http://domain4.com");
 }

if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone"))
 {
 header("Location: http://domain5.com");
 }


$num = Rand (1,3);
switch ($num) { 
case 1: header('Location: http://domain6.com');
break;
case 2: header('Location: http://domain7.com');
break;
case 3: header('Location: http://domain8.com');
break;
}


?>
```

In the first part of code, I wanted only to redirect users from specific countries, then in next part of code, 
users **from all other countries** should be redirected to other remaining links, from which Ipad and Iphone users should go to domain4 and domain5, and other should randomly see 6,7, or 8.
The problem is that only third part, with random redirect, is working in the code, GeoIP not works.
but when delete everything after geoip_close($gi); - GeoIP works perfect.

what I missed in the code ? maybe you see easier way ? also the problem is, that maxmind geoip lite could not recognize all the countries so small part of traffic will be unknown - these users should not be lost.

I used "geoip.dat" from maxmind geocountry lite. It supports only IPv4 addresses, the question is how to combine recognition of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Could be simultaneously "geoip.dat" and "geoipv6.dat" be used ? and how?

Thank you much in advance for your help! I'll be grateful for every opinion.